# List box value specific to form record

Tags: microsoft-access

In Access 2007. How can I make the a value from a list box link to the form that the list box is on.  Sub-form are no problem, you create the form, then when you add the sub form it asks you what field to link with.  But I need to use a list box, when the form opens, the records in the list box should be only those related to the form.  Sounds simple, but I can't figure this out...  Pls aim me in the right direction.

Comment: Multiselect or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no LinkChild/LinkMaster for listboxes, so no automatic way to filter the contents of the listbox like there is with subforms. The fact that you want to filter the listbox is perhaps a clue that you should consider whether or not you should be using a subform instead.

Anyway, if you insist on doing it, you have to filter the listbox manually, either by setting its Rowsource in an appropriate OnCurrent event (if the listbox is on a main form, in the main form; if it's on a subform, likely in the parent form's OnCurrent). Alternatively, you could hardwire the filter criteria with a form control reference (e.g., Forms!MyForm!MyControl) and in the OnCurrent, you'd requery the listbox.

But I'd step back and first determine that a listbox is the right way to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.  I've tried the Forms!MyForm!MyControl method on the listbox rowsource and it simply doesn't run.  The listbox displays all the records in the related table.

I know a subform is the "right" way to do it but they are so ugly, clunky to work with, and risky.

I've already created a different way to enter data in the related table that does not require a subform (a button linked to another form which acts like a dialog box and they fill in the data via list boxes) so now I just want to display those related records in a list box view. Any other suggestions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1130868)